# How to set the Foreground property of the combox dynamically?

Tags: c#, silverlight, combobox, windows-phone-7

I am developing window phone 7 application. I am new to the silverlight. In my application I need a dynamic combobox. So I am using the following code

```
ComboBox CurrenciesCombobox = null;
CurrenciesCombobox = new ComboBox();
                CurrenciesCombobox.Name = "CurrencyCombobox";
                CurrenciesCombobox.SetValue(Canvas.TopProperty, 10.00);
                CurrenciesCombobox.SetValue(Canvas.LeftProperty, 10.00);
                CurrenciesCombobox.Margin = new Thickness(235, 395, 139, 180);
                //CurrenciesCombobox.Foreground = ;
                CurrenciesCombobox.ItemsSource = Currencies;
                CurrenciesCombobox.SelectionChanged += new SelectionChangedEventHandler(CurrenciesCombobox_SelectionChanged);
                ContentPanel.Children.Add(CurrenciesCombobox);
```

In the above code I am unaware of how to set the right hand side of the following statement

```
CurrenciesCombobox.Foreground = ;
```

Can you please tell me how to set the Foreground property of the combobx ?
Can you please provide me any code or link through which I can resolve the above issue ? If I am doing anything wrong then please guide me.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To set it to `White`, use following code:

```
CurrenciesCombobox.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.White);
```

which is same as following:

```
CurrenciesCombobox.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(new Color()
{
    A = 255 /*Opacity*/,
    R = 255 /*Red*/,
    G = 255 /*Green*/,
    B = 255 /*Blue*/
});
```

Second approach here provides more flexibility.

There are other types of Brushes as well: [`Brushes in Silverlight`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc189003%28VS.95%29.aspx).

Also, while working with `Windows Phone 7`, you should consider using theme colors. Take a look at available [theme resources](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff769552%28VS.92%29.aspx).

Answer (score 4):

Try the likes of

```
CurrenciesCombobox.Foreground = (Brush)Application.Current.Resources["PhoneAccentBrush"];
```

further options detailed here

[Theme Resources for Windows Phone](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff769552%28v=VS.92%29.aspx)

or

```
CurrenciesCombobox.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);
```